How to Sign an App and Reference key.properties in Flutter 3.16?
I recently updated Flutter and encountered issues with referencing the key.properties file in my android/build.gradle. It seems the update introduced several changes that affect the way this file is referenced.
Previously, I was able to load the key.properties using the following code snippet:
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    ...
  }

Additionally, the buildTypes block, which was present in earlier versions, seems to have been removed:
   buildTypes {
    release {
        // Add custom signing config for the release build.
        // Temporarily signing with the debug keys so that `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

The signingConfigs also needs to be updated as follows, but I'm unsure where to integrate these changes in the new structure:
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

I've checked the Flutter Gradle Plugin migration guide, but still find it unclear where to add these configurations under the new system. Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to correctly reference and configure the key.properties file in the updated build.gradle?
